# How to display a folder knowing its path?

Tags: finder, folders

How can I display a folder in a different Finder window knowing its path ?

Comment: Where from? From Finder, from Terminal? It's not ideal to just copy the question title in description, provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Go" Menu in Finder there is a "Go to Folder..." menu item.

Alternatively you can use the shortcut:  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  <kbd>G</kbd>

You can

1. Open a new Finder window
2. Use either of those commands
3. Type the path in the dialog that appears

Comment: Didn't you mean [⇧]+[⌘]+[G]?

Comment: th shortcut is command+Shift+G for me..anyway, thank you for the answer ;)

Comment: heh... yep... I was wrestling with figuring out the "kbd" tag and ignored the important part of the answer :D